# How to move table column?

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I want to display a text file on a table and assign some code for each record.

- I can display the text file
- I can assign the code for each record (not yet finish as still under development.)

However, I came to a problem. The table column is not match up for some reason.

[This is what happened. Heading 3 (Pink colour) the fields do not match the table.](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/7633/n990.jpg)

Below is my code:

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <th>Heading 1</th>
  <th>Heading 2</th>
  <th>Heading 3</th>
</tr>

<?php           
$file=file('number.txt');       
foreach($file as $value){   
    $items = explode(" ", $value);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$items[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$items[1]</td>";
}

include("connect.php");//connect to the database.
$sql = mysql_query("select * from code5 where Status='Active' LIMIT 8");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<td>$row[Code]</td>";         
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

can someone spot what am I missing? or give me a hand on moving the table column?

Do I have to implement a CSS file to adjust it manually?

Comment: I'ts not very clear what you are trying to do. Is there something that connects the lines in the file with the rows in the database?

Comment: move last `echo "</tr>";` to outside while loop

Comment: as mentioned on the image above, the pink colour column didnt go to the top. (You can see the white space) is there a way to force this pink column to move back up to the top?

Comment: @Akam: If comments would get the up votes that added to the rep as well.

Comment: @Akam the column is now moving side way.

Comment: @EXphpworld: you need to move first `echo "<tr>";` also into outside foreach loop

Comment: A lot of times it's beneficial to see the HTML your PHP is outputting. Here, it's something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/5u254/). See any issues? Maybe put together what the HTML should look like (statically, on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example) and build the PHP from there.

Comment: is there more than one file?

Comment: @Malachi Only one text file but also need to echo a few records from the database to match those records from the text file. What I am doing is reading from a text file and assign a code from the database for each record. I think my problem is messed up the table code. I think my issue is the TR tag is on different loop.

Comment: @DACrosby Thanks for that site! this will be really helpful in my further development.

Comment: you are going to want something different if you are reading records from the text file and want them to match up to rows from the database.  i could be wrong though.

Comment: thats correct, as I am still in the early stage of the project. I am trying to read the file and echo some result from the database in the same page. thats why the code above look a bit mess and inaccurate. Thanks for @Tjofras he speed up my progress a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines in the file is matched with the rows in the database this should work

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <th>Heading 1</th>
  <th>Heading 2</th>
  <th>Heading 3</th>
</tr>

<?php           
$file=file('number.txt');       

include("connect.php");//connect to the database.
$result = mysql_query("select * from code5 where Status='Active' LIMIT 8");

foreach($file as $value)
{   
    $items = explode(" ", $value);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$items[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$items[1]</td>";
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<td>$row[Code]</td>";         
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td>Empty?</td>";         
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! you speed up my progress a lot! This is my to do list(migration the code) after fixing that table. Can i ask you a side question? I am going to add a IF inside that foreach. for $items[1]. $items[1] = 177, if $items[1] == $row['serial']. If the record's serial is 177 than echo that code. if $items[1] = 277 than echo the match record

Comment: is this doable? or I have to rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you want to do. Do you want to match a line in the file with a row in the database? In that case we need to know what the columns in the table are called and what column in the database should be matched to what column in the file.

Comment: |Serial|Code|Status|Assign,
|177|165156516165|Active|,
|277|555444984849|Active|,
|377|870045608670|Active|,
|177|780807888800|Active|,


if $item[1] = 177 than it will assign 165156516165 to it. if $item[1] = 277 than it will assign 555444984849. will this doable or I have to re think the structure? btw should I open a question for this as this is another question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not opening and closing the  tag correctly.

```
 foreach($file as $value){   
$items = explode(" ", $value);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$items[0]</td>";
echo "<td>$items[1]</td>";
}
```

in that part it would print something like this.

```
    <tr>
   <td>something</td>
  <td>something</td>
<tr>
  <td>something</td>
 <td>something</td>
<tr>
   <td>something</td>
<td>something</td>
```

You would need to open and close the tr tag inside the loop or outside.

Comment: I am thinking that the code needs to go inside of the `foreach` loop actually